# Passing php variables from php1 to php2, then having php2 return a new value assigning to variable from php1

Tags: php

This may sound really broken but essentially my intentions are for in php1, have a  name for example validate to match a regex, if it fails to meet the conditions it will then redirect to php2 where there awaits a form where a user can retype it and submit it back to php1 where it will do the checks again. Then finally in the first php, if everything works ok it will echo it back.

Also how would i expand it so multiple things such as credit cards etc. can be validated too?

Thanks

php1

```
if (isset  ($_POST["CardHolder"]))  {
cardholder = $_POST["CardHolder"];
cardholder = sanitise_input($cardholder);

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,40}$/", $cardholder)) {
        $errMsg .= "First name can only contain alpha characters, please re-enter";
        $newcardholder = $_POST["newcardholder"];
        $cardholder = $newcardholder;
    }
    else {
        $cardholder = $_POST["CardHolder"];
    }


if ($errMsg != "") {
        header("Location: fix_order.php?errMsg=".$errMsg)

}
```

php2 (fix_order.php)

```
if (isset ($_GET["errMsg"])){

    $cardholder = $_GET["errMsg"];

    echo "<form action='process_order.php' method='post'>"
     ."<p><label>$cardholder:</label>"
     ."<input type='text' name='newcardholder'/></p>"
     ."<p><input type='submit' value='Submit'/>";
     "</form>";

}
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you're going to do in fix_order.php page? and another question did you getting value in `$_GET["errMsg"]` this variable?

Comment: What is your problem here? Please tell us.

Comment: @SumonMahmud 
 
In the fix_order.php it contains a form where the user will in this case retype the cardholder of the card, and in addition i want it to take that value of the retyped cardholder, bring it back into php1 have it validate to see if it matches the regex then finally having it echo the new and correct cardholder. Let me know if that still doesn't make sense

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan I just posted a response

Answer (score -1):

When calling `header("Location:...")` you need to give the full and absolute URL.

so `header("Location: fix_order.php")` will not work.

Comment: No it works. You don't have to give a full or absolute url.